# error C4018 with vector size() in c++

Tags: c++

im getting a warning when i use the function .size() with vectors in c++
Heres a sample code:

```
vector<classname*> object;
object.push_back(new classname2);

for(int i=0;i<object.size();i++){
....}
```

i get the warning:

> warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch

I'm not allowed to have any errors or warnings in my final code so i need to get rid of this/find an alternative method, how can i get rid of this?

Comment: `object.push_back(new classname2);` - this is a bad idea.  The vector does not "own" that pointer, so you have to deallocate it manually. Use `std::unique_ptr`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that there is a potential (breaking) issue that one can incur when dealing with signed-to-unsigned comparisons. If you're on a 32-bit machine where a signed `int` is 4 bytes, it could be possible that the size of the vector could exceed the maximum quantity representable by that type. When that happens, you get signed overflow and consequentially Undefined Behavior.

Here are a few alternatives you can uses:

#### [`vector<T>::size_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Member_types):

```
for (std::vector<classname>::size_type i = 0; i < object.size(); ++i);
```

This is guaranteed to be correct as it is the type the `size` returns.

#### Iterators

```
std::vector<classname>::iterator it;

for (it = object.begin(); it != object.end(); ++it);
```

#### C++11: [Range-based for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for (auto& a : object)
{
     // ...
}
```

#### [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t):

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < object.size(); ++i);
```

As doomster said in the comments, `std::size_t` is likely to have the bit-size of your underlying platform.

#### `unsigned int`:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < object.size(); ++i);
```

<sub>Note: By using this, you're assuming that `size` returns a 32-bit integer. Generally this isn't a problem, but you can't be too sure; use any of the above if you can.</sub>

Another tip relative to your code is to use a vector of `unique_ptr`/`shared_ptr` to facilitate memory-management:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<classname>> object;
```

Comment: Assuming that `size()` returns an integral type is a safe assumption.  C++03 §23.1 Table 65 specifies that it returns `size_type` and that `size_type` is an unsigned integral type.  However, assuming that it returns something the same size as `unsigned int` is not a safe assumption.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Allow me to correct myself: I should say rather *32-bit* integer. Because "unsigned integral type" can also include `unsigned long long` (64-bits)

Comment: I'd use `size_t` for indices, it is more likely to have the bit-size of the underlying platform. Using the nested `size_type` is guaranteed to be correct, but it's too long to write.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a vector is always positive. Just use an unsigned int as loop variable:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++)
{
    ...
}
```

An even safer way is to declare your loop variable using size_t, which is the same as unsigned int on most platforms. But since it is the return type of the vector::size() function, your counter variable is guaranteed to have the same value range as the possible size of a vector.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < object.size(); i++)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: `vector::size()` doesn’t return an `usigned int`

Comment: And with most desktop OSs being 64-bit, and ARM chips now getting there, it's also not accurate to say that size_t is the same as unsigned int on most platforms.

Answer (score -1):

Use an unsigned iterator:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++)
{

}
```

Comment: or for (auto i = 0; i < object.size(); i++)
{

}

Comment: Or, if the index is not needed, `for (auto& value : object) { ... }`

Comment: Or `decltype(object)::size_type`.

Comment: -1: `i` is not an `unsigned iterator`, it is an index, and `size()` doesn’t return an `unsigned int`.